# Is there a way to return the bzr function (log.show_log) output as a script automatically so I can re.search through it?

Tags: python, bazaar

There may be a better module for this in the bzrlib in general but I have not been able to find it. I would like to be able to return the output of the bzrlib function: `log.show_log()` as a script so that I could then use the python `re.search` function to find specific information within the human readable version of the log.

I have tried using the simple `str()` function but with no luck. I only get NONE as my feedback.

Here is my code:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-r', '--revnum', type=int, metavar='', required=True, help='Baseline revision number')
parser.add_argument('-d', '--directory',type=str, metavar='',required=True,help='Directory that repository in question is located')
args = parser.parse_args()

r1= args.revnum
d1= args.directory

print ''
print 'Directory containing repository: '+ (d1)
print ''
print ("Input revision number: %s" %(r1))
print ''

b = Branch.open (d1)

lf = log.LongLogFormatter(to_file=sys.stdout, levels=0)

h = log.show_log(b, lf, verbose=False, start_revision=r1, end_revision=r1)

mystring = str (h)

print mystring

result2 = re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+\.\d+ \[merge\]', mystring)
print result2
```

Comment: Please show some of your code - it's hard to tell what's going wrong without looking at it.

Comment: I have updated my original post to include my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

show_log() doesn't return anything, but it instead writes to the log formatter that it accepts as its second argument.

You're specifying `to_file=sys.stdout`, so the output is going to standard output.

You probably want to pass in a io.StringIO() object as to_file instead, and then call .getvalue() on it to get the output.

Comment: Do you mean like  this? `lf = log.LongLogFormatter(to_file=io.StringIO().getvalue(), levels=0)`

Comment: I used this code to get it to work. `old_stdout = sys.stdout` `result = StringIO()` `sys.stdout=result` `(all of my code here using stdout)` Then to get my final string I did `sys.stdout = old_stdout` `print (result.getvalue())`

Comment: There's no need to modify ``sys.stdout``, you can just assign result=StringIO() and then pass in ``to_file=result``